# Programming for Windows, iPad, Droid, and Facebook

Tags: python, windows, facebook, ipad, portability

I want to code semi-simple strategy games that are portable to as many platforms as possible. Ideally, I would like (down the road) to have the option of porting to Windows, Facebook, iPad, and Droid.

As far as I can see, Python is, in some form, viable on all but the iPad.

Question: is there any language/framework that would work on all 4?
(Rather, is there anything "higher-level" than C++ that can do all 4?)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The browser! Here's a nice course by Google and Udacity that teaches HTML5 game development. https://www.udacity.com/course/cs255

Comment: Not bad! Would that be stable enough to support save files, 30+MB of images, and a price tag?
(To refine, when I said simple, I meant low processing requirements, i.e. not Civ V, but I plan on making a polished and marketable product)
Thanks for the help! I'm definitely looking into it.